# Under what conditions does the expression $(x+y)^4$ equal $x^4+y^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In problem 16(c) of chapter 1 of *Calculus*, Spivak asks the reader to determine the conditions under which the expression $(x + y)^4$ equals $x^4 + y^4$. Clearly,

$$ (x + y)^4 = x^4 + y^4 \Leftrightarrow x = 0 \vee y = 0 \vee 4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 = 0 $$

From the preceding problem, we know that $0 \leq 4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2$. If $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ then $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 = 0$. If either $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$ or $x \neq 0$ and $y = 0$ then $0 < 4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2$. I want to show that if $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ then $0 < 4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2$, which is intuitively true. In order to show that $0 < 4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2$, it suffices to show that $6xy < 4x^2 + 4y^2$, but I'm not sure how to demonstrate that this inequality is true. I would presumably derive it from the ordered field axioms in conjunction with the local assumptions of the problem.

Comment: That's because I stated the problem incorrectly. It should have read $(x + y)^4 = x^4 + y^4$. Sorry about that.

Comment: quadratic formula in x (or y)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the identity
$$4x^2+6xy+4y^2=x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2+(x+y)^2+(x+y)^2.$$

Any square $w^2$ is $\ge 0$, with equality iff $w=0$.  The sum of objects that are $\ge 0$ is $\ge 0$, with equality only when all the objects are $0$. This forces $x=y=0$.

**Remark:** The approach above is minimalist in that we use only facts true in **all** ordered fields. If we are willing to use properties such as existence of square roots of positive numbers, then we can complete the square in the traditional way.

Comment: This makes sense. So from $0 < (x + y)^2$, $0 < x^2$ and $0 < y^2$ we have $0 < x^2 + y^2 + 3(x + y)^2$. So the only case where $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 = 0$ is $x = 0$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: Run the argument the other way. From $4x^2+6xy+4y^2=0$ conclude that $x=0$ **and** $y=0$ (and, superfluously, $x+y=0$).  So the possibilities (from the original $4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3=0$) are $x=0$ **or** $y=0$ or both are $0$, which is included in the **or**.

Answer (score 0):

You have $(x+y)^4 - (x^4 + y^4) = 2 x y (2 y^2 + 3xy + 2 y^2)$.

To find the zeros of $2 y^2 + 3xy + 2 y^2$, use the quadratic formula to get $ y = \frac{x}{4} ( -3 \pm i \sqrt{7})$, hence the only zero (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is $(0,0)$.

It follows that the zeros are $x=0$ or $y=0$.